# backbone-paginator fullCollection contains additional models after reset

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-paginator

I reset my collection with an array filtered from the original collection.

```
var applyFilters = function() {
    if (queryfilters.indexOf('no_counts_module') > -1) {
        this.collectionFiltered.reset(this.collectionFiltered.filter(function(site) {
            return !/,?Counts,?/.test(site.get('modulescsv'));
        }));
    }
}.bind(this);
```

After this function runs, `this.collectionFiltered` has the three models I expect, but `this.collectionFiltered.fullCollection` (I'm using [backbone-paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator).) has six models, three of which were not part of the array used to reset the collection and do not match the filter. As a result, my model count displayed on the page shows `1-6 of 6` rather than `1-3 of 3` since that is counted from `fullCollection`.

`fullCollection` is changing with the reset. Its original length is eight. It *does* include the three expected models which are passed to the reset. Those occur first in the collection followed by three additional models which are the models that do not match the filter (although not *all* the models from the original collection that don't match).

Why does my `fullCollection` contain models that are not part of the array passed to the reset?

**UPDATE:** I now believe my filters may be getting clobbered by backgrid-filter. It looks like it's running its search again after I have applied the custom filter, and that collection is overwriting my collection built from the filter.

Comment: how do you define fullCollection ?

Comment: Sorry @FrançoisRichard. I included backbone-paginator as a tag but forgot to mention it in the body of the question. That's where the fullCollection gets made. I believe this is where the magic happens: https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/blob/dd3089328c2c35653ea854b05cb43f1ad0e9227b/lib/backbone.paginator.js#L351

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the solution but I think this may be that you are calling .fullcollection before the your collection has finished to totally fetch.

Second possibility check your regex if it's really correct.

Could you provide exemples of your models ?

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't think it's a fetching problem because the reset shouldn't fetch. It should reset the existing collection with only the models I'm passing in. I'm passing a filtered array of modules from the collection I originally fetched, but I'm not running a fetch since I don't need to go back to the API. I just need to filter inside the collection I've already fetched.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure my regex is correct. I want to match any string with `Counts` and one or zero commas leading and trailing. I could probably even take out the commas and just match `Counts`. It's probably not the best regex for what I need to do, but it does seem to match correctly since the filtered array and the collection have the correct models after running `applyFilters()`. It's only the `fullCollection` that's wrong.

Comment: Here's JSON of a few models: https://gist.github.com/raddevon/ac64479cf374f11e734e